# How can I make a C macro for defining function typedefs?

Tags: c, function, pointers, macros, typedef

I want to take this:

```
typedef int (*PTR_FUN)(int);
typedef int (*PTR_FUN_FUN)(PTR_FUN, PTR_FUN);
```

And define it like this:

```
MAKE_FUNCTION_TYPE(PTR_FUN, int, int);
MAKE_FUNCTION_TYPE(PTR_FUN_FUN, PTR_FUN, PTR_FUN, int);
```

...where the number of arguments is dynamic, and the last argument is the return type.

If not possible to put the last arg as return type, then as the second arg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a **variadic macro**, which can take an arbitrary number of arguments. The syntax is `#define MACRO(fixedarg1, fixedarg2, ...)`. In the body of the macro, you simply use `__VA_ARGS__` to refer to all of the variable arguments.

Unfortunately, you can't make the last arg the return type, because you have to treat the entire block of variable arguments uniformly and they must come last. However, you can make the second arg the return type very easily:

```
#define MAKE_FUNCTION_TYPE(name, ret, ...) typedef ret (*name)(__VA_ARGS__)

MAKE_FUNCTION_TYPE(v_i, int);
MAKE_FUNCTION_TYPE(i_v, void, int);
MAKE_FUNCTION_TYPE(ii_cp, char *, int, int);
```

This is equivalent to

```
typedef int (*v_i)();
typedef void (*i_v)(int);
typedef char * (*ii_cp)(int, int);
```

which you can check using `cc -E`.

Comment: Technically `...` can't match zero macro arguments, so `MAKE_FUNCTION_TYPE(v_i, int)` is officially invalid. But most compilers allow it anyway. C++20 will make it legal, but I don't know of similar plans for C.

Comment: Though in C, `int (*)()` is not a type you want anyway. You want `int (*)(void)`.

Comment: @aschepler, C23 is likely adopting `__VA_OPT__` which will provide means of solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the return type last, that's complicated, but [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) (which works with both C and C++) can help do it:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comparison/greater.hpp>

#define PP_VARIADIC_BACK(...) \
  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(BOOST_PP_DEC(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)), \
    BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__))
#define PP_VARIADIC_POP_BACK(...) \
  BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_GREATER(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), 1), \
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_POP_BACK(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__)), \
    (void))

#define MAKE_FUNCTION_TYPE(name, ...) \
  typedef PP_VARIADIC_BACK(__VA_ARGS__) (*name) PP_VARIADIC_POP_BACK(__VA_ARGS__)
```

The helper macro `PP_VARIADIC_BACK` requires at least one argument and results in the last argument. The helper macro `PP_VARIADIC_POP_BACK` requires at least one argument. When it gets more than one argument, it results in parentheses containing a comma-separated list of all arguments except the last one. When it gets exactly one argument, it results in the text `(void)`.

Then those can just be put together with the `typedef` and `(*name)` parts. The final semicolon is left off since your example uses provide a semicolon right after the macro.

[Example preprocessor output on coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1d34f54d54778be)